# Implementation of Work Manager-like work scheduling for Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, android-workmanager, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-desktop

how can I implement workmanager like work scheduling in multiplaform
the intent is to develop offline first desktop app with compose desktop
the logic would be done implemented (i tried store 5 and it just didn't seem to cut it for me) and periodic syncing of bookkeeping database done with work manager